# String passed through sender parameter cannot be used by the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, sender

I am passing a String (postID) between two view controllers (respectively DiscoverVC and DetailVC) using the sender parameter of the method **performSegue**. 
When the destination VC is presented, I can actually see that the String I passed is correctly assigned to a local variable “postID” (since I can print it). But when I try to perform some operations on it, such as querying in the Firebase Database, it seems like the String is no longer present. I don’t know how to solve this problem even though it seems stupid to solve.

This is the code of the viewDidLoad() method of the destinationVC

```
var postID = “”
override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("this is the postID that I get from previous VC \(postID)")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateViewDetail()
}
```

This is the method updateViewDetail() which makes some operations with the Firebase database. It is trying to retrieve the post using the PostID String.

```
func updateViewDetail(){
    Api.Post.observePost(with: postID) { (post) in
        print("post id inside \(post.id)")
        guard let postUid = post.uid else{
            return
        }
        self.fetchUsers(uid: postUid) {
            self.post = post
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to print the post.id inside the closure it is nil. Do you know how I can solve this problem?
Just for the sake of completion, this is the code of the observePost method that retrieves the post object from the FIRDatabase:

```
func observePost(with id : String, completion: @escaping (Post)-> Void) {              
    REF_Posts.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snaphsot) in
        if let dict = snaphsot.value as? [String : Any]{
            let post = Post.transformPost(dict: dict, key: snaphsot.key)
            completion(post)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

This is the code of `prepare` method set in the previous VC :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        let postid = sender as! String
        detailVC.postID = postid
    }
```

Comment: `observePost` method has postID ?

Comment: @jawadAli no, I'm using PostID String, passed from the previous VC to take the informations of the post object from the Database. It doesn't need to have postID since I'm just placing it in the parameter "id"

Comment: yes ... what i was asking is your post has values in `observePost` method ... from where you are calling completion(post)

Comment: How exactly is argument `id` contained in the `post` object that you pass into the completion handler? Is it contained in the `dict` dictionary?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD The method searches the child node of the Post Reference equal to the id passed, then, it creates a post object that has all the elements contained in that node (such as post.id and post.caption) then it returns that element in the completion handler.

Comment: @jawadAli yes it should have all the values attached to the post it should retrieve but the problem is that when I pass the argument of postID inside the `observePostMethod` it retrieves a nil value

Comment: where you are setting postID ?

Comment: do you have teamviewer ?

Comment: @jawadAli I'm setting it in the previous VC, I attach the code of the `prepare` method in the previous VC in the 1st EDIT.

Comment: do you have teamviewer ?

Comment: @jawadAli no I don't have it.

Comment: install it ...https://www.teamviewer.com/en/